# Facebook Ads API: is it possible to de-activate and then re-activate an adgroup?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

Say I created an adgroup. Later when the deal sold out I want to deactivate it. Then if I have new stock I want to re-activate this ad again. 
Currently, I de-activate ad with changing adgroup_status to 'deleted'. However, when changing the attribute back to 'active', I got error 'Invalid Ad Status Transition -- The adgroup is already deleted [HTTP 500]'. 
Is there any way to achieve what I want? I'm thinking about update the adgroup_status to 'draft' or 'pending' rather than 'deleted' for de-activation, but no idea if this is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to move from deleted to another state, if you want to pause an adgroup, set its status to paused. it's probably best to pause the entire campaign as there are a few non-obvious quirks with the state model.
For example if you pause an ad group in an active campaign, then edit the ad group's other fields, it'll move back to 'active' once the changes are approved by Facebook. In a paused ad campaign, it'll stay paused.